# Could not determine client ID from request error while refreshing token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using installed application client ID for my Google Oauth setup. After user authentication is successful using **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync**, I received access token from Google and I was able to use Google APIs as expected. After 1 hour or so, if I need to access Google API, I'm using [**credential.RefreshTokenAsync**] function to refresh the access token. Even with the refresh token, I was able to access the Google APIs as expected.

But at random scenarios, I'm receiving the below exception while refreshing the token. I can confirm that there is no issue with client ID since my client ID is read from a text file which is permanent.

Update: Adding code and more details.

Due to limitations in Google API for my application scenario, I've designed the app as following:

1. User will setup their Google account from a Windows forms app. ("First time authentication code" I've mentioned below)
2. I'll use the token response received from Google in Step 1 in a different app using same client ID/secret ("Issue scenario" code I've mentioned below). So, Google API will see whether the token response is already available, if available, it won't display auth page and check whether token is expired or not. If expired, I'll refresh the token using RefreshTokenAsync.

Code:

```
//First time authentication

 credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                                        new ClientSecrets
                                        {
                                            ClientId,
                                            ClientSecret,
                                        },
                                        scopes,
                                        GoogleAuthUser,
                                        CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(filepath, true)).Result;

                var oauthSerivce = new Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2.Oauth2Service(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Appname",
                });

//Issue scenario:

credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId,
                        ClientSecret,
                    },
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(filepath, true)).Result;

            if (credential.Token.IsExpired(credential.Flow.Clock))
            {
                if (credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
```

Exception details:

```
 (Inner Exception #0) Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_request", Description:"Could not determine client ID from request.", Uri:""
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse.<FromHttpResponseAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.TokenRequestExtenstions.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<FetchTokenAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<FetchTokenAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<RefreshTokenAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential.<RefreshTokenAsync>d__22.MoveNext()<---
```

Comment: Maybe item 4 : https://blog.timekit.io/google-oauth-invalid-grant-nightmare-and-how-to-fix-it-9f4efaf1da35

Comment: Why don't you just let the client library refresh it for you that's what its designed to do.   Please edit your question and include  [example].   Sounds to me like either your client id is bad or your trying to use a refresh token that was created with a different client id.

Comment: @jdweng no the error message for that is different it actually says the refresh token is expired.

Comment: @DaImTo If client id or refresh token is wrong, the issue should occur always. As I mentioned before, issue occurs randomly during testing. Also, I've added some more details in the question. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

> User will setup their Google account from a Windows forms app. ("First time authentication code" I've mentioned below)

Actually your not going to see the authorization code at all unless you decide to create your own implementation of IDatastore which you don't appear to be doing since your using fileDatastore.  You have not mentoned the authorization code anywhere in your quesiton.

> I'll use the token response received from Google in Step 1 in a different app using same client ID/secret ("Issue scenario" code I've mentioned below). So, Google API will see whether the token response is already available, if available, it won't display auth page and check whether token is expired or not. If expired, I'll refresh the token using RefreshTokenAsync.

Actually GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker handles all this by checking the directory that the credentials are stored in by fileDataStore denoted by the user you are passing. Your code is defiantly not doing what you think its doing.

## Issue one mixing of users and confusing filedatastore

I see two issues with your code. The first being that you are mixing users.  In the following code you are storing the user credetnails for a user named `GoogleAuthUser`.

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                                        new ClientSecrets
                                        {
                                            ClientId,
                                            ClientSecret,
                                        },
                                        scopes,
                                        GoogleAuthUser,
                                        CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(filepath, true)).Result;
```

In the following code you are storing / reading redetinals for a user called `user`

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId,
                        ClientSecret,
                    },
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(filepath, true)).Result;
```

FileDataStore stores the credetinals for the user in %appdata% on your machine and the user is denoted by what ever string you send.  If your mixing the strings on two different calls then its not going to be able to authenticate the user.   Please consult [FileDatastore Demyistified](https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/) for more information

## issue two exired

The Client library is designed to handle authorization though the credentials object once it is loaded into a service you should not need to concern yourself with it anymore let the library desired when is the best time to refresh the access token

```
 if (credential.Token.IsExpired(credential.Flow.Clock))
            {
                if (credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
```

## issue three question

What is this even for?

```
  var oauthSerivce = new Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2.Oauth2Service(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Appname",
                });
```